# PHP Get Total Sum Value From XML Response Tree

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml, response

Im trying to get the total sum value from a specific xml tree like so:

Example response from 3rd party:

```
<response>
    <date_start>2014-02-01</date_start>
    <date_end>2014-02-25</date_end>
    <source>Web</source>
    <partners>
        <partner>
            <partner_id>99</partner_id>
            <number_of_leads>11</number_of_leads>
        </partner>
        <partner>
            <partner_id>101</partner_id>
            <number_of_leads>17</number_of_leads>
        </partner>
        <partner>
            <partner_id>103</partner_id>
            <number_of_leads>38</number_of_leads>
        </partner>
    </partners>
</response>
```

I would like the end result to be a variable like this: **$lead_total = '66'**;  The repeating "partners" block could have anywhere from 1 to perhaps 100 partners listed.  So I would like to be able to iterate thru all partners and display the number_of_leads sum.

So far Ive been doing it this way, which is ugly and not very expandable, and I have to create new file each time I add additional partner IDs to the query string below:

```
$target_url = 'https://........&Partner_ID=99,101,103.....';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($target_url);

$number_of_leads1 = $xml->partners->partner[0]->number_of_leads;
$number_of_leads2 = $xml->partners->partner[1]->number_of_leads;
$number_of_leads3 = $xml->partners->partner[2]->number_of_leads;

if(!$number_of_leads1) { $number_of_leads1 = '0'; }
if(!$number_of_leads2) { $number_of_leads2 = '0'; }
if(!$number_of_leads3) { $number_of_leads3 = '0'; }

$lead_total = $number_of_leads1 + $number_of_leads2 + $number_of_leads3;

header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: max-age=0 no-cache must-revalidate no-store');
header('Expires: -1');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
echo "
<root>
    <item> 
        <value>{$lead_total}</value> 
        <text>{$currenttime} CST, {$currentdate}</text>
    </item>
</root>
";
```

Im not very good at creating loops, or arrays, or more advance php, and such so any help to clean this mess up is greatly appreciated.  Ideally, getting the total number_of_leads based on the Partner_IDs in the url string would be awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just loop in your xml file and sum all `number_of_leads` while looping as follow

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($target_url);
$total=0;
foreach($xml->partners->partner as $data)
{    
    $total += $data->number_of_leads;
}
echo 'Total is: ' . $total;
//output Total is: 66
```

[**Live Working Demo**](http://codepad.org/W5ycrLIN)

**Note** in demo i used `simple_load_xml_string` because i placed your xml as a string, you are instead downloading as a file so use `simple_load_xml_file` as you did correctly

Comment: This worked great. Much simpler than use than what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

select all `<number_of_leads>` with `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$leads = $xml->xpath("/*/partners/partner/number_of_leads");
```

calculate the sum with:

```
$totalleads = array_sum(array_map("intval", $leads));
```

**Comments:**

- the `xpath`-expression selects all specified nodes and stores them as array in `$leads`
- it is an array of `simplexml elements`, therefore we use `array_map()` to convert these objects to integer values
- and use `array_sum()` - it does what its name suggests ;-)

see it working: https://eval.in/105695

I've seen the sum built within the `xpath`-expression, which would again shorten the code. I wasn't able to get it working, though.